# Ajuda sobre PrintPage no c#

Tags: c#, textbox

Quais os processos para colocar uma marca d'água(imagem) no formulário que será criado pelo c#

```
  private void Imprimir_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        Font fonte = new Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


        e.Graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), fonte, Brushes.Black, 20, 20);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("TESTE DE LABEL",fonte,Brushes.Black,20,150);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text, fonte, Brushes.Black, 300, 250);


    }
```

Comment: Pensei em colocar a imagem na Form e deixa-la invisível, só sendo visível na impressão, tipo quando clico para imprimir ela se torna visível no formulario

Comment: user de drogas pesada kkkkkkkkkkkkkk, respondi abaixo. mas nao me contive que nick engraçado :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que você esteja usando o **PrintDocument**.

```
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument(); 
printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);
```

Então adicione o **Graphics** lá:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics; 
g.TranslateTransform(200, 200); 
g.RotateTransform(e.PageSettings.Landscape ? 30 : 60); 
g.DrawString("DRAFT VERSION", new Font("Arial", 75, FontStyle.Bold), 
             new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, Color.Black)), 0, 0);
```